# Check value for 2 second

Tags: c#

i have an integer whose value changes, i like to know if there is a way to check whether the value is same for 2 sec.

like if num = 2 for 2 sec then Messagebox.show("for 2 sec");

cause my numbers are changing instantly.

Comment: Why not make num a property and implement inotifypropertychanged

Comment: If you want to be able to determine if the value has changed in the last two seconds you can save the date/time of the last update.  Compare that to the current date/time and you have your answer.  Being notified after a value has remained unchanged for two seconds is a different matter and Anon's comment applies.  You'll likely need a separate thread with a timer that you reset on each change.

Comment: if (...........)
                {
                    fingerNum++;
                    
                }
                if (fingerNum == 1)
                {
                    
                    
                   MessageBox.Show("Do you like to open Notepad", "Open", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    
                }
but the problem is that when ever fingernum gets 1 it shows message and fingernum value changes with gesture recognition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be superfluous, I like using [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).  This will tick every 2 seconds to look for a change:

```
private DispatcherTimer _checkNumberTimer = null;
private int _myNumber = int.MinValue;
private int _lastValue = int.MaxValue;

public Constructor1(){
  _checkNumberTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
  _checkNumberTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(HandleCheckNumberTick);
  _checkNumberTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 2); //Timespan of 2 seconds
  _checkNumberTimer.Start();
}

private void HandleLoginOrderDispatcherTick(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
  if(_myNumber == _lastValue){
    MessageBox.Show("Alert!");
    _checkNumberTimer.Stop(); //If you want
  }
  _lastValue = _myNumber;
}

private void SomeOtherCodeAffectingMyNumber(int something){
  _myNumber = something;
}
```

You would need to include `System.Windows.Threading`.

The good thing about DispatcherTimer is that it handles all the work of delegating to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

How about make it keep track of when it last changed?

```
int _num;

public int num
{
    get { return _num; }
    set 
    {
        if(value != _num)
        {
            _num = value;
            numModified = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}

public DateTime numModified { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing `INotifyPropetyChanged` interface from `System.ComponentModel` - [here is the description with example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a `property`, a `Bool`, buffer and a `Timer`. Now change the `setter` like this:

```
    public int Variable
    {
        get { return _variable; }
        set
        {
            yourtimer.Stop();
            IsLongerThanTwoSec = false;
            _variable = value;
            yourtimer.Start();
        }
    }
```

Create a `timer` like this and set this `.Elapsed`:

```
        bool IsLongerThanTwoSec = false;
        Timer timer = new Timer(2000);
        timer.Elapsed += (e, s) => IsLongerThanTwoSec = true;
```

if IsLongerThanTwoSec is `false` it is not; otherwise, it is.